# Open Fancybox on a timer

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have been on this for a number of hours and just give up.

I want Fancybox to trigger on a timer (Say after 5 seconds). I can get it to open on page load and close after a certain amount of seconds. However every example I have found online I can't get to work. Here is the code I am using

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $(".video").fancybox({
        maxWidth    : 560,
        padding     : 9,
        maxHeight   : 315,
        fitToView   : false,
        width       : '100%',
        height      : '100%',
        autoSize    : false,
        closeClick  : false,
        openEffect  : 'fade',
        closeEffect : 'fade',
afterLoad: function(){
   setTimeout( function() {$.fancybox.close(); },5000);
  }
    });
$('#video').trigger('click');
});
```

This is the html:

```
<a id="video" class="video fancybox.iframe"
href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/aqut-wQ72Yk?autoplay=1&autohide=1&modestbranding=1&showinfo=0">Test</a>
```

Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you were almost there:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#video').trigger('click');
        setTimeout(function(){
            $.fancybox.close();
        }, 5000)
    }, 5000);
});
```

On DOM ready, in 5 seconds the fancybox should open, then 5 seconds later it should close.

A little more explanation:

DOM ready simply means that the web browser has made it to the bottom of your HTML. Keep in mind that "ready" is not the same thing as "loaded", because even after the browser reads all the way through the HTML, the images and any additional javascript still need to load.

Inside of the first setTimeout() function you have the `click` trigger, and another `setTimeout` function which gets called in 5 seconds and closes the fancybox.

Comment: That's great. I don't understand it one bit but it works. Thanks!